# instance variable not passed to partial (rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Instance variables not bring passed to partial as I am facing undefined method error.

Articles controller:

```
  def index
    @articles = Article.order("created_at DESC").all
  end
```

Article partial (_article.html.erb)

```
    <h3><%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %></h3>
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= render 'article', article: @articles %>
```

Alternative way of passing local variables didn't work too:

```
<%= render 'article', :article => @articles %>
```

Comment: Are you sure that @articles is ever getting set ?

Comment: As per rails 5 docs you can simply use: `render @articles` and ensure `@articles` is really set.

Comment: Your code doesn't work because there is no method `title` on `ActiveRecord::Collection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a collection of `@articles` as `article` in your `<%= render 'article', article: @articles %>`

Perhaps the following would work?

**index.html.erb**

```
 <% @articles.each do |article| %>
   <%= render 'article', article: article %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Even better: `<%= render partial: 'article', collection: @articles %>`, no need for the loop.